# loading multiple non-CSV tables to R, and perform a function on each file.

Tags: average

First day on R. I may be expecting too much from it but here is what I'm looking for:
I have multiple files (140 tables), and each table has two columns (V1=values & V2=frequencies). I use the following code to get the Avg from each table:
I was wondering if it's possible to do this once instead of 140 times!
i.e: to load all files and get an exported file that shows Avg of each table in front of the original name of the file. 
-I use read.table to load files as read.CSV doesn't work well for some reason. 
I'll appreciate any input!

> Sum(V1*V2)/Sum(V2)

Comment: Please show us the format of the files.

Comment: they are delimited text files. I can open them with a read.table command individually.